# Reset file input in jquery fileupload plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

can some one please help me with how to reset the input file after file has been uploaded, I am using the jquery fileupload plugin. . .i need to reset the input file so that the upload doesnt happen more than once. . . . .thanks in advance !!!

---

```
    $($files).each(function(index, selectorFile)
    {
        var counter = index + 1;
        $(selectorFile).fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                $(document).on('click', '#startUploadButton', function(event)
                {
                    console.log("in add "+selectorFile+" >> click event");
                    validateFileUpload();
                    $("#startUploadButton").attr('disabled', 'true');
                    $(selectorFile).attr('disabled', 'true');
                    $.ajax({
                                type : 'POST',
                                url : localStorage.getItem("contextPath")+"/content.createContent.htm",
                                data : {
                                    code : '0'+counter,
                                    name: $('#name'+counter+'').val(),
                                    originalName: $('#name'+counter+'').val(),
                                    description: $('#description'+counter+'').val(),
                                    tags: $('#tags'+counter+'').val(),
                                    type: $("#selectFileType"+counter+"").chosen().val(),
                                    extension: $('#name'+counter+'').val(),
                                    size: $('#name'+counter+'').val()
                                },
                                success : function(response)
                                {
                                    alert(response);
                                    data.formData = {id: response};
                                    data.submit();
                                },
                                error : function(e)
                                {
                                    alert('Error : ' + e);
            //                      alert('Error : '+e.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                });
//              $(document).off('click', "#uploadButton");
            },
            done: function (e, data)
            {
                if(controllMultipleHit == 2)
                {
                    $(document).off('click', "#startUploadButton");
                    console.log("IN fileupload"+counter+" DONE");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    controllMultipleHit = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    controllMultipleHit++;
                }
            },
            progressall: function (e, data)
            {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress'+counter+' .bar').html(progress+"%");
                $('#progress'+counter+' .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                if(progress == 100)
                {
                    $("#startUploadButton").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(selectorFile).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
    function reset_field(e) {
    e.wrap('<form>').parent('form').trigger('reset');
    e.unwrap();
}
```

You can call this like

```
reset_field($('#fileupload1'));
```

Comment: iJay, thanks for the reply, but it aint working buddy, the file input doesnt get reset and a second button click makes the file to upload again. . . .

Comment: check for any errors in console and plz post your code ...of how you are passing the file element into the reset function

Comment: I did, there are no errors. . ., It aint a very difficult task, but simply things dont work when using plugins. . .

Comment: whats you file upload control id?

Comment: Sorry, but do U want to kno how the input file looks like??
         <input id="fileupload1" class="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/content.uploadContent.htm" >

Comment: Yes that is how I am calling it,
 $(document).on('click', "#resetFile", function(event) {
  reset_field($('#fileupload1'));
 });
 function reset_field(e) {
     e.wrap('<form>').parent('form').trigger('reset');
     e.unwrap();
 }